# Enums, clicking a button for x,y coordinates

Tags: c#, enums

I'm creating a Connect 4 game. However I'm stuck on clicking on the button and it will generate the x,y coordinates. Example: press button 1 - generates x:1 y:2 etc.

This is my code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Output_textBox.AppendText("You have inserted in Column 1");
   Output_textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

   TextBox[] boxes = { textBox11, textBox12, textBox13, textBox14, textBox15, textBox16 };
   if (currentState == Gamestate.Player1Turn)
   { 
      if (boxes[counter].BackColor != SystemColors.HotTrack && boxes[counter].BackColor != Color.Red)
      {
         boxes[counter].BackColor = SystemColors.HotTrack;
         return;
      }

      counter = counter + 1;
   }
   else if (currentState == Gamestate.Player2Turn)
   {
      if(boxes[counter].BackColor != SystemColors.HotTrack && boxes[counter].BackColor != Color.Red)
      {
         boxes[counter].BackColor = Color.Red;
         //  m_Connect4GameLogic.PlayerPlayed(player_enum, 1, 3);
         return;
      }
      counter = counter + 1;
   }
}
```

The comment bit is what someone advised me to write a similar code to it. However I don't really know how to use enums.

How do you use enums, and how would you the implement "click button1 (generates the x,y co-ordinates) and the button will pass information to the game logic "?

Comment: Info about enumerations in C# can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: oops sorry forgot to add the question (thanks for reminding me)

Comment: Aren't you already using enums? It seems `Gamestate` is an enum. Don't you want to use the same enum to execute the game logic?

Comment: You are asking two _very different_ questions in the same post - game logic and how to use enums - please make a second post for your question about enumerations.

Comment: so i wouldnt need to create a second enum for example player?